# Largest Contentful Paint Error in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I've just launched a Website and have some issues to Test it  in Google PegeSpeed Insights, because it shows every time a error in Largest Contentful Paint (See Attachment)[Largest Contentful Paint Error in WordPress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbgvR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Then there probably is no LCP candidate. I have seen this a few times before.

Comment: Is there a possibility to make PageSpeed Insights measure the Website correctly?